# Unable to fix "could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread"

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to spring hibernate.
I am using sprin 4.3.8 and Hibernate 5.2.

I tried solutions available on the net and I have all of them in my code, yet I am getting this error please help me resolve this.

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:456)
at com.travello.daoImpl.ActivityDAOImpl.getActivity(ActivityDAOImpl.java:43)
at com.travello.model.SpringMain.main(SpringMain.java:17)
```

Here is the ActivityListDAOImpl:

```
@Transactional
public class ActivityDAOImpl implements ActivityDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionfactory;



public SessionFactory getSessionfactory() {
    return sessionfactory;
}

public void setSessionfactory(SessionFactory sessionfactory) {
    this.sessionfactory = sessionfactory;
}

@Override
public ActivityList getActivity(int activity_id) {
    Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
    ActivityList activity = session.get(ActivityList.class, activity_id);
    return activity;
    }
}
```

The Main method:

```
public class SpringMain {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext         ("spring.xml");
    ActivityDAOImpl dao = (ActivityDAOImpl) context.getBean("activityDao", ActivityDAOImpl.class);

    ActivityList activity = dao.getActivity(1);
    System.out.println(activity.getActivityName());
    System.out.println("Done");


}

}
```

The spring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.travello" />

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="activityDao" class="com.travello.daoImpl.ActivityDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionfactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

I have @Transational annotation applied and the bean for the same in the spring.xml yet there's this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to your spring.xml. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) and [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config.html)

Answer (score -1):

I have had a similar error, the easiest solution is to add @Transaction with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

You will not get this error after that and would work perfectly.

Comment: That won't help here as he is simply missing the `<tx:annotation-driven />` to enable `@Transaction` processing.

Comment: Hibernate needs a transaction to create a session, be it a manual or declarative. once you provide a transaction, you should be good.

Comment: That comment doesn’t make sense. You need a session to create a transaction... Not the other way around.